# Google Drive as FTP Server

Tags: ftp, sftp

Is there a way to use Google Drive as an FTP Server? 
I mean I have host, username and password and using Filezilla I can access GDrive folders, upload and download data and automate backups with many softwares.
It isn't important if the protocol is FTP or SFTP.

Does GDrive allow this feature? In positive answer, how can I obtain my credentials?

Does also DropBox allow this features?

Comment: The current solution I'm using is to install the application on my end-host, and then synchronize, move, copy all files with rsync or a simple backup application.

Answer (score 20):

What about running the **google-drive-ftp-adapter** application in your local pc and then connect your filezilla client to that application? The google-drive-ftp-adapter application **is not an online service**, but its an alternative solution to connect to google drive through ftp.

The google-drive-ftp-adapter is an open source application hosted in github and it is a kind of standalone ftp-server java application that connects to your google drive in behalf of you, **acting as a bridge (or adapter) between your ftp client and the google drive service**. Once you have running the google-drive-ftp adapter, you can connect your preferred FTP client to the google-drive-ftp-adapter **ftp server** in your localhost (or wherever the app is running, like in a remote machine) to manage your files.

I use it in conjunction with beyond compare to synchronize my local files against the ones I have in the google drive and it serves well for the purpose.

This is the current github link hosting the google-drive-ftp-adapter repository: https://github.com/andresoviedo/google-drive-ftp-adapter

Comment: Is it banned by Google? I cannot sign into my account.

Answer (score 5):

I couldn't find a direct GDrive/DropBox solution.  I'm also surprised there's no lazy solution for a free ftp host.  Windows azure offers a ftp server "FTP connector" that's fairly easy to turn on at:
https://portal.azure.com

You can get a free 1 GB account by selecting "View All" machine types during your deployment.

Answer (score 4):

With **google-drive-ftp-adapter** I have been able to access the *My Drive* area of Google Drive with the FileZilla FTP client.  However, I have not been able to access the *Shared with me* area.

You can configure which Google account credentials it uses by changing the **account** property in the **configuration.properties** file from *default* to the desired Google account name.  See the instructions at http://www.andresoviedo.org/google-drive-ftp-adapter/